# if statement not passing - groovy scripting

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

i am having an issue passing a particular condition. i am displaying a value from a json and as you can see from the screenshot, it displays the value 2210 within the log, however it outputs that the condition has `fail` when it should be `true`. I cannot see why it is failing, does anybody have ideas why or what i can try to fix it so it will pass?

[image]

Below is the code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def hotelidjson = json.jet2_hotel_id
hotelid = context.expand( '${#TestCase#hotelid}' )


assert hotelidjson != null

if (hotelidjson == "2210")
    log.info "pass"
else
    log.info "fail"


log.info hotelidjson
```

UPDATE:

The response string outputs:

```
INFO:[{jet2Awards=[], awards=[{awardType=Certificate of Excellence, images={small=https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CERTIFICATE_OF_EXCELLENCE_small-24283-5.jpg, large=https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CERTIFICATE_OF_EXCELLENCE_2016_en_US_large-24283-5.jpg}, year=2016}], num_reviews=342, rating_image_url=https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/4.5-24283-5.png, jet2_hotel_id=2210, rating=4.5}]
```

The json of the response is here:

```
[{
   "rating": "4.5",
   "rating_image_url": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/4.5-24283-5.png",
   "num_reviews": 342,
   "jet2_hotel_id": 2210,
   "awards": [   {
      "awardType": "Certificate of Excellence",
      "year": "2016",
      "images":       {
         "small": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CERTIFICATE_OF_EXCELLENCE_small-24283-5.jpg",
         "large": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CERTIFICATE_OF_EXCELLENCE_2016_en_US_large-24283-5.jpg"
      }
   }],
```

Thank you

Comment: But `hotelidjson` is `[2210]` not `2210`... Do you want to check if the string is equal to that value or **contains** that value? Also the log is inconsistent with the code since there are 3 values but only 2 fails. That cannot happen with the provided code.

Comment: (1) Please don't put screenshots of code or outputs in questions. Copy/paste the text instead. It's easier to read and to work with. (2) The commented-out code is not relevant to your question, so please don't include it.

Comment: (3) show us the value of the string `response` (trimming out irrelevant elements)

Comment: @m0skit0 even if I change the if condition to check if hoteldidjson = [2210], it fails.. For the log, I ran it and it displayed a log of 3 and then I commented out one of the logs and not cleared it, hence why you're seeing 5 logs when it should be 2

Comment: Can you show us what `hotelidjson` is? `log.info hotelidjson.class`

Comment: @m0skit0 [‎05/‎01/‎2017 16:16] Jagrit Gyawali: 
log.info hotelidjson.class outputs INFO:class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Then you're comparing a list with a string

Answer (score 0):

You're testing for `"2210"` but `hotelidjson.toString()` is `"[2210]"` so the object is definitely not the String `"2210"`.

What it actually is, is harder to tell. This is a general problem for programmers screaming "`println()` says they're the same, but `assertEquals()` says they're not" at their IDEs. But consider that a `List<String>` containing `"Hello"` prints as `["Hello"]` and the String `"[\"Hello\"]"` also prints as `["Hello"]`.

Furthermore, an object of this class prints as `["Hello"]`:

```
 class Hello {
       String toString() {
           "[\"Hello\"]"
       }
 }
```

So, you need to be a bit more thorough before assuming that two objects that give the same `println()` output, are actually equal.

The smartest thing to do is to run your test in a debugger. Put a breakpoint in before the assertion, an examine the variable at that point.

A dumber option, but with less setup overhead if you're not already a habitual debugger user, is to add some more diagnostic logging. For example, `log.info hotelidjson.getClass()`

I thoroughly recommend getting into the habit of using a debugger, however. It soon repays the effort, in hours of saved time.

---

Update, now that you've shown the JSON. I would expect `hotelidjson == 2210` to pass. `2210` and `"2210"` are not equal, since one is a number and the other is a String.

(I note that in the comments you've discovered it's a List. I don't know why that is.)

Comment: Hi Slim, it is the value of the json

Comment: @1990prog then update your question so that it's accurate. Don't say "the json", say `json` so that we know you're referring to the variable in your code (better still, give it a better name. Now it's been parsed, it's no longer JSON. It's a data structure.)

Answer (score -1):

Since `hotelidjson` is actually a list and not a string (`[2210]` is the string representation of the list), comparing it directly with a string will always return false. You can do:

```
if (hotelidjson == [2210])
```

or

```
if (hotelidjson[0] == 2210)
```

Carefully using `def` you should.

PS: thanks to slim for the hint ;)